# How can i instantiate a different subclass based on common identifier (java)

Tags: java, oop

I have a class for a tile.

```
public abstract class Tile {
    public Position pos;
    public char chr;
}
```

And many different classes that extend tile. Each subclass has its own identifier char.
Now I have a function that receives a char and a position and needs to create and return a new instance of a tile subclass fitting the char in given position.
Is there an elegant OOP way to do this other than run through all of the options?

Comment: How do different subclasses of `Tile` differ from one another?

Comment: If you have an identifier, why do you use subclasses?
You should probably get rid of the "identifier" and make this part of the subclasses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So for me use of an identifier like this is a bit of a design flaw.

You could add something like the following to the abstract class:

```
public static Tile factory(char identifier, Position p) {
   Tile value = null;
   switch (identifier) {
      case `x`: {
        value = new XTile(p);
        break;
      }
      default {
        // throw an exception or provide a default
      }
   }
   return value
}
```

Effective Java (third edition) Item 21 "Prefer Class hierarchies to tagged classes" might provide an alternative to your design.

Comment: Depending on your needs another approach could be to use an `enum`.